# Как быть с двумя spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Пытаюсь сделать что бы 2 spinner нормально существовали на одной странице и при их изменениях менялись нужные textxiew. Пока что работает только spinner с тестом, но тот что с начинкой отказывается работать и выводит ошибку

> 'onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)' is already defined in 'com.example.scpr.pizza

Я пытался изменить название, но это ни к чему не привело.

[image]

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class pizza extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
   private Spinner spinner,spinner2;
   private static final String[] paths = {"1 pizza", "2 pizza", "3 pizza","4 pizza"};
   private static final String[] paths2 = {"baze"};
   private AdapterView<?> parent;
   private View view;
   private int position;
   private long id;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizza);
// тесто

       spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(pizza.this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);}



   protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizza);
// начинки

       spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(pizza.this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths2);

       ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter = null;
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
       spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   }


   //ингридиенты

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //мука
       TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.florout1);
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               textView.setText("0.25kg");
               break;
           case 1:
               textView.setText("0.5kg");
               break;
           case 2:
               textView.setText("0.75kg");
               break;
           case 3:
               textView.setText("1kg");
               break;
       }
       //вода
       TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.waterout);
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               textView2.setText("150ml");
               break;
           case 1:
               textView2.setText("300ml");
               break;
           case 2:
               textView2.setText("450ml");
               break;
           case 3:
               textView2.setText("600ml");
               break;
       }
       //дрожжи живые
       TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.beerout);
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               textView3.setText("2.5gr");
               break;
           case 1:
               textView3.setText("5gr");
               break;
           case 2:
               textView3.setText("7.5gr");
               break;
           case 3:
               textView3.setText("10gr");
               break;
       }
       //соль
       TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.saltout);
       switch (position) {
           case 0:
               textView4.setText("5gr");
               break;
           case 1:
               textView4.setText("10gr");
               break;
           case 2:
               textView4.setText("15gr");
               break;
           case 3:
               textView4.setText("20gr");
               break;
       }
   }

//начинка
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tomout);
   switch (position) {
       case 0:
           textView.setText("0.25kg");
           break;
       case 1:
           textView.setText("0.5kg");
           break;
       case 2:
           textView.setText("0.75kg");
           break;
       case 3:
           textView.setText("1kg");
           break;
   }
}









   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       //empty
   }

   @Override
   public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
       super.onPointerCaptureChanged(hasCapture);
   }



}
```

Comment: нужно все переделать.  есть только onCreate  а onCreate1 нет,если вы слушаете один слушатель на несколько spinner'ов то нужно идентифицировать с какого из них пришло сообщение по view.getId()

Comment: Слейте все эти ваши "двойники" методов в один `onCreate` и один `onItemSelected` в котором по параметру `view`, как вам уже сказали выше, поймете от кого пришел вызов и сделаете правильный `if-else` для его обработки.